# If I do {member.mention} twice will it mention two different users in my message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering if that I put two of the {member.mention} will it ping/mention the two different users I @'ed in my message. For an example: my message is "@user1#0001 is better than @user23#0001" will it ping both of those users and not ping one user twice: (like ping @user1#0001 twice rather than ping user1 and user2) here is my code so you can know what I am talking about:

```py
import discord
import os
import replit
import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready!")
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="over PRFL"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> request trade'):
    emoji1 = '✅'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    emoji2 = '❌'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji2)
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await message.channel.send(f'<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> offer {member.mention} for {member.mention}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if your input is `<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> request trade @user1#1234 @user2#9876`, or whatever your command usage is, your output will be `<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> offer @user1#1234 for @user1#1234`. Because `member` is the first mention of the message. I don't exactly know what you're trying to do so my answer might be not the answer that you're looking for.

If inputs are like `:emoji: request trade @user#1234`, you can do:

```py
if message.content.startswith('<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> request trade'):
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.channel.send(f'<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> offer {message.mentions[0].mention} for {message.author.mention}')
```

If inputs are like `:emoji: request trade @user1#1234 @user2#9876`, you can do:

```py
if message.content.startswith('<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> request trade'):
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.channel.send(f'<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> offer {message.mentions[0].mention} for {message.mentions[1].mention}')
```

Comment: I think what I was trying to accomplish the second answer. If the second answer pings first 2 members that are mention in the message?

Comment: Second answer pings the 2 mentioned member in the message.